# Was Kylo Ren's lightsaber destroyed?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

I read that Kylo Ren's trademark [crossguard lightsaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kylo_Ren%27s_lightsaber) was destroyed during his encounter with Rey. I don't know if him nearly having his hand cut off created this belief in somebody's mind but I simply don't recall seeing that.

**Did I miss it, or have I just been misinformed?**

Answer (score 17):

All we know is that Rey hit the hilt of his lightsaber (with the blade of her saber), that it turned off and then came out of Kylo Ren's hand. That it was *definitely* broken is not mentioned in the script.

> Rey closes her eyes for a long beat. When Rey opens them, she is
>   centered, fortified, and she POUNDS BACK, SINGLE HANDED SWIPES,
>   hitting Ren's gnarly, spitting saber with incredible FORCE. It's so
>   fast now, so furious, that Kylo Ren FALLS BACK -- She ATTACKS HARDER!
>
> **Ren gets up again but she HITS HIS SABER'S HILT -- HIS BLADE GOES
>   FLYING OFF, TUMBLING INTO THE SNOW** -- and she SLASHES AGAIN AND AGAIN
>   AND HITS KYLO REN SQUARE IN THE HEAD AND CHEST. HE GOES DOWN, SUDDENLY
>   A FEARFUL MAN, A LARGE BURN SCAR SLASHED ACROSS HIS FACE! He still
>   reaches for his saber.

Nor in the [Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))

> **He was up again in an instant, but not in time to fully deflect a
>   following blow from Rey’s weapon. He succeeded in blocking it, but he
>   still took the full force of the strike against the haft of his own
>   lightsaber.** The weapon went flying into the snow. Unarmed, he raised a
>   hand and utilized the Force to fend off one slashing blow after
>   another, until finally her fury penetrated his remaining defenses.
>   Taking a glancing blow to the head and chest, he went down, a
>   prominent burn slashed across his face. Weakened, he reached out
>   toward his lightsaber, trying to draw it to him.

Nor the [Junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization))

> Staggering back to his feet, **his parry could not match the strength of
>   her swing. It cast his lightsaber out of his grasp.**

Nor [Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Rey's Story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force_Awakens:_Rey's_Story)

> She intensified her attacks, sensing more than seeing where he would
>   strike next. **Her blade cut across Kylo’s face before connecting with
>   his saber hilt.** Kylo’s weapon went flying into the snow.

---

The [Official Graphic Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_Graphic_Novel_Adaptation) shows it slipping from his hand *undamaged*.

[image]

Comment: Ok.  I saw it opening night and I thought it was something I overlooked.  It didn't seem right to me but only seeing it once left me thinking it could be true because of what happened to Kylos hand.  You're right though.  Can't trust a wiki, indeed.

Comment: @Goku - I'm watching a dodgy version of the scene frame-by-frame and it's just not clear. The blades clash, there's lens-flare and then he's not holding it.

Comment: I appreciate your effort.  In my personal opinion, based on what I saw, I thought the saber was knocked out of his hand.  So, based on what you're seeing/saying I'm gonna assume it is in fact NOT destroyed.  I just don't think there's enough evidence to prove it's gone.

Comment: Although if he is trying to reach it I would assume that it still works.

Comment: @Thomas - At the least, it would work as a way of blocking her next strike.

Comment: @Richard normally not....as a lightsaber goes through other hilts unhindered quite often (see episode 1)

Comment: @Thomas - An interesting secondary question; "Why didn't Rey's strike go through Kylo Ren's Saber handle?"

Comment: @Richard I think that that question can potentially be answered by Stephen Colbert's analysis of the weapon:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycg_3vhOfTk

Comment: @Spar10Leonidas - Except that Colbert was 100% wrong about how Ren saber works. The side bits are simply plasma vents, not separate beams.

Comment: @Richard I'm aware that they are vents.  But the quillons span from the same crystal as the main blade does, and I didn't see anything in the film (or anywhere else) to indicate that they couldn't stop a lightsaber blade.  In fact, the visual dictionary for TFA refers to them both as "quillons" and as "blades."  It does appear that there is a weak spot in the hilt (unless it's made of a lightsaber-resistant material, although I've seen no evidence of that yet).  I'm guessing that would be hard to hit, but I guess we'll have to wait and see in the next film (I'm hoping it wasn't destroyed).

Comment: @Spar10Leonidas - You make some good point, albeit I'm still reasonably sure that Colbert is wrong. As you say, we may see in the next film, or not.

Answer (score 3):

I think it was just knocked from his hand. When he sits up after Rey slashes him across the face you can see it lying in the snow and it appears to be intact.

Answer (score 2):

Per *The Last Jedi*, his lightsaber wasn't destroyed, since he uses the same one throughout the film. This is supported by [*The Last Jedi: The Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary), which shows the same lightsaber on Page 28: Kylo Ren:

[image: Screenshot of The Last Jedi: The Visual Dictionary showing Kylo Ren's lightsaber detail]

Compared to the corresponding photo from [*The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary), it's the same lightsaber:

[image: Screenshot of The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary, showing the same lightsaber]

Answer (score 1):

I've just watched a frame-by-frame of the HD digital version on iTunes, and it's still unclear, but it appears as though Rey hits Kylo's blade very close to the hilt, knocking it out of his hand and deactivating it, but not destroying it.

If you have the iTunes version the critical sequence is between 1:57:33 and 1:57:37. Kylo Ren's lightsaber is at an angle, with the tip being pressed down into the snow. We see Rey's saber enter frame at 1:57:33 (frame 1), clearly in front of the hilt of Kylo Ren's saber which is nearer to his hand. There's a clear distance of perhaps a foot between the hilt itself and the point of impact:

[image]

At the moment of impact (1:57:33 frame 3) we can also clearly see Kylo Ren's hand on the hilt of his saber, BEHIND the point of impact. There is a brief white flash as the sabers connect, suggesting that it's the blades that are impacting.

A moment later we see the saber deactivating, and try as I might I can't see if there are sparks or any other sort of indicator that the saber is damaged through the particle effects. Also, when Kylo Ren and Rey are seperated, we can see Kylo Ren's saber in the snow next to him - it's not 100% clear that the hilt is intact but there doesn't appear to be any physical damage to the portion that's visible above the snow:

[image]

To me this suggests that in film canon it's likely that Kylo Ren's saber is still intact.

*(Stills were taken from the iTunes HD version of Star Wars Episode VII: The Force Awakens, which is ™ and © Lucasfilm Ltd)*

Answer (score -5):

**Yes**, it was. [Check wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kylo_Ren's_lightsaber)

> Ren defeated and injured the former stormtrooper known as Finn in the duel, but was overpowered in the ensuing duel with Rey. Rey successfully channeled the Force within herself to fight back and cleaved Ren's lightsaber in two.

**Edit: This is not true. My information is outdated and hence inaccurate. My source no longer supports this data.**

Comment: Wookieepedia doesn't say that any more.